# Where can I find CSharpEvaluator?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

What Anders presents at minute 60 of this video seems pretty cool

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/

However, I can't find it.
Is it released? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that it was not released. There is actually an [alternative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) which for me does same thing. and was there for years

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was in mono. (mono.sharp)
(can't watch the video, I'm currently at an evening course so I might be thinking about the wrong CSharpEvaluator)